# Simplify a list of excel cells to create a Range

Tags: c#, algorithm, excel, vsto

I want to create a Excel.Range object from a list of cell references which are dynamically generated.

```
Excel.Range outputRange = sheet.get_Range(strCellRange, Type.Missing);
```

Since the strCellRange can get quite large, it gives com exceptions. 
Therefore I want to simplify it to have range notation with union.

e.g.

```
string strCellRange = "F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,F12,G12,H12,I12,J12,K12,L12,F17,G17,H17,I17,J17,K17,L17,F22,G22,H22,I22,J22,K22,L22,F27,G27,H27,I27,J27,K27,L27";
```

to

```
string strCellRange = "F2:L2,F7:L7,F12:L12,F17:L17,F22:L22,F27:L27";
```

1. Is there any Excel method to create a Range object with lot of cell references?
2. Is there a known algorithm to achieve above simplification (a matrix algorithm)?

Comment: In Excel VBA you would use `Union` for this to accomplish 1&2. I'm unsighted as to how - or if - you can achive this via `C#`

Comment: @brettdj: Yes I could use application.Union(<range1>,<range2>). But AFAIK in my original string the comma "," is also the union operator.

Comment: **More Information:** The method 
    sheet.get_Range(<cell_ref>, Type.Missing);
 methods accepts only a string of length 255 maximum as its first argument. The 255 characters includes all spaces, commas $ signs etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gayan,

In `VBA` you could force your direct string to a range with

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strCellRange As String
strCellRange = "F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,K7,L7,F12,G12,H12,I12,J12,K12,L12,F17,G17,H17,I17,J17,K17,L17,F22,G22,H22,I22,J22,K22,L22,F27,G27,H27,I27,J27,K27,L27"
Set rng1 = Range(strCellRange)
Set rng1 = Union(rng1, rng1)
Debug.Print rng1.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, but the OP's problem is the fact that the generation of the Range given the string generate an exception due to the number of cells in the string...

Comment: @brettdj: You answered my problem of simplification, I can now take self union whenever approaching the cell limit. Ultimately I might hit another limit with the simplified version also, but then I can break and have different ranges.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli Actually No, it isn't the OP issue as union reduces the cells in string. Gayan, yes, if the simplified union still provided issues (has it?) then (1) splitting the string into certain lengths first, or (2) error resting the `Union` result would be workarounds

Answer (score 2):

**VBA**

```
Function Unionize(src As Range) As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim unionizedRange As Range

For Each cell In src
    If unionizedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set unionizedRange = cell
    Else
        Set unionizedRange = Union(unionizedRange, cell)
    End If
Next

Set Unionize = unionizedRange
End Function
```

**c#** (rough cut, didn't run it through compiler for syntax)

```
Excel.Range Unionize(Excel.Range src)
{
    Excel.Range unionizedRange;

    foreach (Excel.Range cell in src)
    {
        if (unionizedRange == null)
        {
            unionizedRange = cell;
        }
        Else
        {
            unionizedRange = Application.Union(unionizedRange, cell);
        }
    }
    return unionizedRange;
}
```

**EDIT**: Based on @brettdj's solution

```
Excel.Range outputRange = sheet.get_Range(strCellRange, Type.Missing);
strCellRange = Application.Union(outputRange, outputRange).Address(false, false);
```

Comment: From what I understand, the shortened versionof strCellRange is not the OP's goal. It's just a way to bypass the fact that trying to get the Range from the original string raise an exception

Answer (score 2):

This could be a starting point (it doesn't work for columns beyond Z, and doesn't identify rectangles):

```
    private string CompactRangeStringByRows(string strCellRange)
    {
        SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<char, char>> rows = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedList<char, char>>();
        foreach (string aCell in strCellRange.Split(new Char[] { ',' }))
        {
            char col = aCell[0];
            int row = int.Parse(aCell.Substring(1, aCell.Length - 1));
            SortedList<char, char> cols;
            if (!rows.TryGetValue(row, out cols))
            {
                cols = new SortedList<char, char>();
                rows[row] = cols;
            }
            cols.Add(col, col);
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool first = true;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SortedList<char, char>> rowCols in rows)
        {
            char minCol = '0';
            char maxCol = '0';
            foreach (char col in rowCols.Value.Keys)
            {
                if (minCol == '0')
                {
                    minCol = col;
                    maxCol = col;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (col == maxCol + 1)
                        maxCol = col;
                    else
                    {
                        AddRangeString(sb, first, rowCols.Key, minCol, maxCol);
                        minCol = col;
                        maxCol = col;
                        first = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            AddRangeString(sb, first, rowCols.Key, minCol, maxCol);
            first = false;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void AddRangeString(StringBuilder sb, bool first, int row, char minCol, char maxCol)
    {
        if (!first)
            sb.Append(',');
        sb.Append(minCol);
        sb.Append(row);
        if (maxCol != minCol)
        {
            sb.Append(':');
            sb.Append(maxCol);
            sb.Append(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once fully developed this will be the best answer. Very useful +1.
I can generate the cell references with R1C1 style. or even (row^col) which will make the algorithm much useful. Will definitely try this when time permits. But for now I think brettdj's solution is ok.

Comment: Developed a similar algorithm to "manually" get the lines and rectangles in the range. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First have some classes holding references...

```
public class CellRef : IEquatable<CellRef>
{
    public int Row { get; private set; }
    public int Col { get; private set; }

    // some more code...
}

public class CellRange : IEquatable<CellRange>
{
    public CellRef Start { get; private set; }
    public CellRef Stop { get; private set; }

    // some more code...
}
```

Then the algorithm and method...
The list of cells need to be put in a List and **sorted** before passing to this method.

```
    public static string GetSimplifiedRangeString(List<CellRef> cellList)
    {
        #region Column wise simplify (identify lines)

        Dictionary<CellRef, CellRef> rowRanges = new Dictionary<CellRef, CellRef>(new CellRefEqualityComparer());

        int currentRangeStart = 0;
        for (int currentRangeStop = 0; currentRangeStop < cellList.Count; currentRangeStop++)
        {
            CellRef currentCell = cellList[currentRangeStop];
            CellRef previousCell = (currentRangeStop == 0) ? null : cellList[currentRangeStop - 1];

            bool cont = IsContigousX(currentCell, previousCell);

            if (!cont)
            {
                currentRangeStart = currentRangeStop;
            }

            if (!rowRanges.ContainsKey(cellList[currentRangeStart]))
                rowRanges.Add(cellList[currentRangeStart], cellList[currentRangeStop]);
            else
                rowRanges[cellList[currentRangeStart]] = cellList[currentRangeStop];
        }

        #endregion


        #region Row wise simplify (identify rectangles)

        List<CellRange> rangeList = new List<CellRange>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<CellRef, CellRef> range in rowRanges)
        {
            rangeList.Add(new CellRange(range.Key, range.Value));                
        }            
        Dictionary<CellRange, CellRange> colRanges = new Dictionary<CellRange, CellRange>(new CellRangeEqualityComparer()); 

        currentRangeStart = 0;
        for (int currentRangeStop = 0; currentRangeStop < rangeList.Count; currentRangeStop++)
        {
            CellRange currentCellRange = rangeList[currentRangeStop];
            CellRange previousCellRange = (currentRangeStop == 0) ? null : rangeList[currentRangeStop - 1];

            bool cont = IsContigousY(currentCellRange, previousCellRange);

            if (!cont)
            {
                currentRangeStart = currentRangeStop;
            }

            if (!colRanges.ContainsKey(rangeList[currentRangeStart]))
                colRanges.Add(rangeList[currentRangeStart], rangeList[currentRangeStop]);
            else
                colRanges[rangeList[currentRangeStart]] = rangeList[currentRangeStop];
        }

        #endregion


        #region Simplify ranges (identify atomic lines and rectangles)

        StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<CellRange, CellRange> ranges in colRanges)
        {
            string rangePart = string.Empty;
            if (ranges.Key.Equals(ranges.Value))
            {
                if (ranges.Key.Start.Equals(ranges.Key.Stop))
                {
                    rangePart = ranges.Key.Start.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    rangePart = ranges.Key.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rangePart = new CellRange(ranges.Key.Start, ranges.Value.Stop).ToString();
            }

            if (retStr.Length == 0)
            {
                retStr.Append(rangePart);
            }
            else
            {
                retStr.Append("," + rangePart);
            }
        }

        return retStr.ToString();

        #endregion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the given two cells represent a line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentCell">Line start</param>
    /// <param name="previousCell">Line end</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool IsContigousX(CellRef currentCell, CellRef previousCell)
    {
        if (previousCell == null)
            return false;
        return (currentCell.Row == previousCell.Row) && (currentCell.Col == (previousCell.Col + 1));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether the given two cells represents a rectangle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentCellRange">Top-left cell</param>
    /// <param name="previousCellRange">Bottom-right cell</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool IsContigousY(CellRange currentCellRange, CellRange previousCellRange)
    {
        if (previousCellRange == null)
            return false;

        bool sameVertically = (currentCellRange.Start.Col == previousCellRange.Start.Col) && (currentCellRange.Stop.Col == previousCellRange.Stop.Col);
        bool contigous = (currentCellRange.Start.Row == currentCellRange.Stop.Row) && (previousCellRange.Start.Row == previousCellRange.Stop.Row) && ((previousCellRange.Stop.Row + 1) == currentCellRange.Stop.Row);
        return sameVertically && contigous;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any method to retrieve long range of cell references. I would prefer taking complete sheet and then navigating with in it through codings.